# Merge records in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge

[image]I have [this schema of batabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajOKT.jpg) schema of batabase. **A lot of clients that have many phone numbers are stored as separate clients** because erlier I could not import a client with two or more phonenumbers

I need to write script, that would merge clients with same name, surname and coordinates fields. Also i need change client_id foreign key in every dependent table.

Comment: *I need to write script*...ok, then write the script. Please note StackOverflow is not a script writing service, free of charge. We troubleshoot earnest efforts. There is no specific question here. Consider freelancing your needs.